# How do we solve this triangle using law of sines?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> [image]
>
> ABC is a right triangle, $AB \perp AC, DE \perp BC, |AD| = |BD| = 3$. The area of ABC is $6$ times of the area of BDE. Evaluate $|AC|$.

How do we solve this triangle using law of sines?

Comment: There's easier ways than the sine rule. is that required?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\angle ABC = \theta$, then $EB = 3\cos\theta$ and $AB=6$. Since the two triangles are similar, the area scale factor is

$$ \frac{A_{BDE}}{A_{ABC}} = \left(\frac{EB}{AB}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{\cos\theta}{2}\right)^2 = \frac16 $$

$$ \implies \cos^2\theta = \frac23, \sin^2\theta = \frac13, \tan^2\theta = \frac12 $$

Finally

$$ AC = AB\tan\theta = \frac{6}{\sqrt{2}} = 3\sqrt{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$A_{ABC}=6A_{BDE}$$ so we get
$$6\frac{AC}{2}=6\frac{DE\cdot BE}{2}$$ with
$$\frac{DE}{3}=\frac{AC}{BC}$$ and $$\frac{BE}{3}=\frac{6}{BC}$$ we get
$$3AC=3\cdot 3\frac{AC}{BC}\cdot \frac{18}{BC}$$ so $$BC^2=54$$ and $$6^2+AC^2=54$$

Comment: Did you use sine law?

Comment: No i used the similarity of triangles.

Answer (score 0):

$\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DEB$ are similar.$m\angle ACB=m\angle EDB$. As per sine law,$\frac{c}{sinC}=\frac{a}{sinA}=\frac{b}{sinB}$ in $\triangle ABC$. Likewise, $\frac{d}{sinD}=\frac{b_1}{sinB}=\frac{e}{sinE}$in $\triangle DEB$.

For the sake of convenience, $\overline{AB}=c, \overline{AC}=b,\overline{BC}=a$ in $\triangle ABC$ and $\overline{DB}=e,\overline{BE}=d,\overline{DE}=b_1$ in $\triangle DEB$.

$m\angle E$ and $m\angle A$ are $90^\circ$ angle in $\triangle DEB$ and $\triangle ABC$ respectively.So, using sine law,

$\frac{c}{sinC}=\frac{b}{sinB}=\frac{a}{sinA}=a$ because $\sin{90^\circ}=1$.

Likewise, $\frac{d}{sinD}=\frac{b_1}{sinB}=\frac{3}{sinE}=3$ because $\sin{E}=\sin{90^\circ}=1$

$\sin{D}=\sin{C}$.

So, ${d}=3\sin{C}$ but $\sin{C}=\frac6a$.

So $d=\frac{18}{a}$. But area of $\triangle ABC$ is $6\times$ the area of $\triangle DEB$. It can be rewritten as $3b=3db_1$

So,$b=\frac{18}{a}b_1$ $\Rightarrow a*\sin{B}=\frac{54}{a}\sin{B}$

$a^2=54 \Rightarrow a=\sqrt{54}=7.348469$

$a^2-c^2=b^2$ So,$54-36=18,\Rightarrow b=\sqrt{18}$

Answer (score 0):

A triangle is solved if there is sufficient information to apply a congruence rule, e.g. SSS, SAS, AAS, and HL.

We have that the ratio of areas between the larger and smaller triangles is 6 to 1. This implies the ratio if corresponding legs is $\sqrt{6}$:1.

We know the hypotenuse if the smaller triangle us 3. By the length ratio, the hypotenuse of the larger triangle us 3$\sqrt{6}$. Now the pythagorean theorem can tell us the length of the remaining unknown side.

By the sine rule, the sine of either angle divided by the opposite side is the reciprocal if the hypotenuse length. We know each leg length, so we can determine the sine, and by inverting, the angle itself

Comment: @TuriocTHeRed, You have computed the ratio of corresponding sides of a triangle $\sqrt{6}:1$ because the area of larger  triangle is 6 times greater than the smaller triangle. I want to know whether this rule is applicable to any triangle or any specific types of triangles

Comment: More general than that. In Euclidean geometry, the ratio of the areas if two similar figures, whatever the shape, is the square of the length of corresponding parts.  For proof, I think you can start by proving it for triangles and squares, then, given that non curved plane figures can be broken up into triangles, generality follows. As for as squares and triangles themselves, I think you can prove algebraically, or straight edge and compass. Euclid has a proof for circles but I don't know it.